ReactJS calling parent function from child component not showing updated parent state
I'm trying to implement a custom multistep login function using functional components. From the parent component I'm passing a parent state hook and a function that the child should call on form submit, but when the child calls the parent function it doesn't have the updated state (is empty).
 export default function() 
     {
       const [input, setInput] = useState({
                                           email: "",
                                           password: ""
                                          });
       function handleSubmitEvent(e)
        {
          e.preventDefault();
           /****************/
           console.log("handleSubmitEvent input",input)
           return;
        };
                        
                        
        useEffect(() => {
                          console.log("useEffect input ", input)
                          /*this shows the updated input
                          value correctly as the user 
                          fills the information*/
                         });
                
        const [ loginSteps, setLoginSteps] = useState(
         {
           steps:[
                  <CheckRegistry input={input} setInput={setInput} handleSubmitEvent={handleSubmitEvent}/>,
                  <CheckPassword/>
                 ],     
                  stepIndex:0 
         })
                    
       return (
               <div>
                <button onClick={handleSubmitEvent}></button>
                {/* if I click this button inside the parent 
                   the handleSubmitEvent shows the updated 
                   "input" state correctly
                 */}
                {loginSteps.steps[loginSteps.stepIndex]}
         </div>
        )
     }

On the Child I have:
    export default function(props) 
    {
        
     const handleInput = (e) => 
                               {
                                const { name, value } = e.target;
                                props.setInput((prev) => ({
                                                           ...prev,
                                                           [name]: value,
                                                          }));
                               };
    
   return (
            <>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {props.handleSubmitEvent(e)}}>
                            
            <input
                   className="email-input" 
                   type="email"
                   name="email"
                   onChange={handleInput}
             />
                <button></button> 
                {/* if I click this button inside the child 
                    the handleSubmitEvent is empty
                 */}
            </form>
            </>
        )
    }


What's going on here, can some please explain and provide the right way to do it?

What if you change your button to <button type="submit"><button/>? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Thanks for the answer but no changes. The function gets called but input is empty, maybe is calling a copy of the state and not the actual parent state.

Can you put a string to identify which console.log is which? Also something that might help is adding input to your useEffect dependency array, so you can check when that state is changing. Another thing that might help is React Dev Tools.

I think putting the component as state would make your code more complex and hard to maintain, you can achieve the composition pattern in React for a multi-step form.

Thank you, I'm very new to ReactJS (3 months) I will check the composition pattern

You shouldn't put your steps component inside a state (useState).
Move your component outside of useState declaration. The function passed to the component will only execute the latest function it received. In which, the very first function it receives has the input value of an empty string.
The Child component will remember this handleSubmitEvent function:
function handleSubmitEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /****************/
    console.log(input) // input value is {email: '', password:''}
    return;
};

The parents receive and execute the new input state value, but the children will only execute the old function, which stores the value of empty email and password.
Solution:
const steps = [
    <CheckRegistry input={input} setInput={setInput} handleSubmitEvent={handleSubmitEvent}/>,
    <CheckPassword/>
]
const [ loginSteps, setLoginSteps] = useState({     
    stepIndex:0 
})

Moving the steps outside of the useState should fix your problem.

Tips: Understand how JavaScript works behind the code, every time you get a new input value, the function also gets re-created into a new function. The child component that previously received a function in useState declaration, will always use the same first function, which stores the empty email and password.
Why didn't the child component get the latest re-created function like the parent? useState parameter will only get executed once, during its initial rendering. There is a reason why the documentation said: useState(initialState) (ref: here)
